# Mobile Chat - How to store data?

Tags: chat

I'm trying to figure out the best way to store data for a mobile chat program.

Basically I will be able to make a group with my friends and they should also see the same group I made.

I'm assuming the best way is to store the data locally on each phone, and then when someone sends a message, it goes to the network, and the network sends that data to each recipients local phone so that it updates the local data.

That way when people are opening up the application, the previous few messages are still visible, since the program will check local data storage.

Is this the proper way to create mobile chat? Or should there be no local storage of data?

Comment: Can you show us some code you've tried? It looks like you want us to write code or figure out the best algorithm to solve your problem. That seems too much like work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way will be to store data locally and on the server as well. The reason are as follows

- Local data is for the users and will allow the saving on data costs instead of the users always having to get their chat data online everytime they logon. My assumption is that you want to have offline messages the way that Whatsapp chat client has.
- Server data is for your reference and also good practice in order to provide the user with data up to a certain point in history if they have lost their device and they login to another device.

I hope this helps and answers your question.

Comment: thank you, the what'sapp example is exactly what I was thinking...I was pretty sure local data storage was needed but since I'm new to programming and couldn't seem to google this, just wanted to confirm. Thanks!